# Model Viewer for web doesn't show View in AR button when passing Private Signed URL or Public URL from AWS S3

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, augmented-reality, model-viewer, web-ar

I started using ModelViewer 1.9.2 by google in my angular project to render the 3d model. Possibly surface detection to augment the objects for now. Initially i used 3d models inside application assets to augnment, which went fine and i am able to augment. Now i want to fetch the file from an s3 bucket and pass the url to the model viewer. This is where i am stuck. Neither the public URL nor the Private Signed URL is letting me augment the 3d Object

this is my component.html

```html
<section class="py-5">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="">
          <model-viewer src={{demo_fileURL}} ios-src="" alt={{demo_name}} poster="assets/images/loading_1.gif"
            environment-image="neutral" shadow-intensity="3" shadow-softness="1" camera-controls auto-rotate autoplay ar
            ar-modes="webxr scene-viewer quick-look" ar-scale="auto">
          </model-viewer>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

this is my component.ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { S3FileService } from '../s3-access.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-animgirl',
  templateUrl: './animgirl.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./animgirl.component.css'],
  providers: [S3FileService],
})
export class AnimgirlComponent implements OnInit {
  demo_name: string;
  demo_fileURL: string;
  demo_fileName: string;

  constructor(private s3FileService: S3FileService) {
    this.demo_name = 'Animgirl Character';
    this.demo_fileName = 'character_assets/glb/animgirl.glb';

    var baseURL =
      'https://isl-studio.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/AR_Milestone1/assets/';

    // Signed URL from AWS S3 link
    // this.demo_fileURL = this.s3FileService.viewAssetFile(this.demo_fileName);
    
    // Public URL from a different bucket
    this.demo_fileURL = baseURL + this.demo_fileName;
    console.log('Final URL : ' + this.demo_fileURL);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

When i am passing a signed URL to the modelViewer, I am calling an inbuilt s3 service that will let me access the private bucket using the credentials and return me with a signed URL, so that i can pass it to the model viewer

I have enable the CORS policy to both the s3 buckets(Public and private)
here is the CORS policy that I have applied

```html
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://*",
            "http://*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

In both the cases, I am able to see the model viewer - the model preview.
but the "View in AR" button isn't getting enabled.
I have no CORS Access issues.
The device that i am using is an Android ARCore enabled device.
When I pass the same file from local application assets, I am able to see the "View in AR" button so I am sure that there is nothing wrong with the model viewer plugin attached to the angular application.

The problem comes when i pass a public or signed url to the model viewer.
Suggest me if i am missing something in the process.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be because of the model viewer access via NPM.

Please use the CDN - I personally prefer. Add the below script to your index.html
Both the private signed URL and the Public URL are working when I switched back to the CDN.

```html
<!--  Include both scripts below to support all browsers! -->

  <!-- Loads <model-viewer> for modern browsers: -->
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Loads <model-viewer> for old browsers like IE11: -->
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/@google/model-viewer/dist/model-viewer-legacy.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Model-Viewer needs to initialize, so right at the start of your logic before retrieving the file from the DB. pass an empty string to it, that should do the trick.

```
this.src = ''
```

or

```
this.demo_fileURL = ''
```